# Issue with some users not seeing the current rows from the sys.dm_tran_commit_table view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, change-tracking

I have been using change tracking for a long time to transfer data to an EDW. So far all the tables have then an SCD type 0 or 1. In the process of setting up an SCD type 2 table, I joined the sys.dm_tran_commit_table into the query. That is when I noticed missing data.

I setup a simple test

```
SELECT MAX(commit_ts), MAX(commit_time) FROM sys.dm_tran_commit_table
```

When I run it I get current values. Other users get values delayed up to a few hours.

| UserId | MAX(commit_ts) | MAX(commit_time) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Me | 1875390 | 2022-10-11 17:21:21.330 |
| Other | 1875200 | 2022-10-11 16:09:30.640 |

I have searched and could not find an answer.

Another related issue I found is 1 DB so far that returns current data for me but other users get values up to 2022-09-29 ( 23 to 11 days ago ). For this one I think there are several issues

- Server is MSSQL 2017 RTM ( no updates have been applied )
- The DB is set to SQL Server 2008 (100)

Thanks

Update 1:

I have tested 6 different systems (SQL2016 through SQL 2017 CU30) and got the same result. The issued with the SQL2017RTM system resolved by itself. The max value in the sys.dm.tran_commit_table is missing current info for non sysadmin users. I modified my test query.

```
SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION(), MAX(commit_ts), MAX(commit_time), GETUTCDATE() FROM sys.dm_tran_commit_table
```

| UserId | CTCV() | MAX(commit_ts) | MAX(commit_time) | UTCDATE() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Me | 434244345 | 434244344 | 2022-10-12 18:33:25.050 | 2022-10-12 18:33:25.050 |
| Other | 434244355 | 434240149 | 2022-10-12 18:25:08.327 | 2022-10-12 18:33:26.287 |

The only thing I could find is

> Change tracking information is stored for all tables (enabled for Change Tracking) in a database in an in-memory rowstore ( syscommittable ). This in-memory rowstore is flushed every checkpoint to the on-disk table ( syscommittab ). Rows from the syscommittab internal table are removed during every checkpoint.

I do not understand why non sysadmin users do not get current data from the sys.dm_tran_commit_table view.

Thanks

Edit 2:

I noticed in the explain plan for non sysadmin users the server would return 0 rows from the SYSCOMMITTABLE but for a sysadmin it does return rows. Both users do get rows from the clustered index scan of the syscommittab. That would explain why users do not see current data.

I now think it is a permission issue. I am still trying to understand what the previous DBA did to the systems.

Comment: Why haven't you applied any updates to your instance? There have been multiple bug and security fixes in the last 5 years.

Comment: I just got access to the system yesterday

Comment: @Larnu - is that a comment based on it being SQL 2017? The [lifecycle page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/sql-server-2017) says that mainstream support ends (coincidentally) today with extended support for another five years.

Comment: No, on the basis it's RTM, @BenThul . The latest release is CU31.